Is it possible to use wildcards in the SoapCore?
In the example below, I would like to have country as one of several possible values, and any unplanned operation to be handled by a specific service, such as calling operation2, operation3, etc. to be handled by a "dead-end" service.
   endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<IService>(opt =>
   {
       opt.Path = "/country/service/operation1";
   });

